# How can I fix the WebGL build error in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a game project in unity. And I want to build this to WebGL. But when it build, it shows error like [image]

I searched the solution, and everyone say "delete using UnityEditor". So I did that, but it has error when I delete that in Photon script.[image]
How can I my game build in Webgl with not delete using UnityEditor. Or How can I fix the error another solution ? Thank you for your anything helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. I use Photon voice chat, but it doesn’t support WebGL. Remove that asset and project build work well.

Comment: Please mark the question is resolved by choosing your own response as correct.